# GET SMTP & Display Name from Shared Mailboxes - Addition to an already working script

Tags: powershell

I have the following script, already working well:

```
$mailboxes = Get-Content "D:\powershell\Permmisions\mailboxes.txt"
foreach ($user in $mailboxes){
get-mailboxpermission -identity $user -ResultSize Unlimited | 
where {$_.user -notlike "*NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} | 
select  @{Name="Displayname"; Expression={(Get-Recipient $_.user.ToString()).Displayname.ToString()}}, @{Name="primarysmtpaddress"; Expression={(Get-Recipient $_.user.ToString()).primarysmtpaddress.ToString()}}, user, @{Name="AccessRights";Expression={$_.AccessRights}} | Export-Csv "D:\powershell\Mailboxes\Mailbox_Permmisions.csv" -Append
}
```

Output on the csv, looks like this:

[image]

What i wish to do next is to add three more columns to the CSV output:

- Member user`s - samaccountname
- Shared/Target Mailbox`es - Display Name
- Shared/Target Mailbox`es - Smtp Address

Target Mailbox = Mailbox id i read from mailboxes.csv file, on the start of the script.

Thanks in advance , everyone's help is most appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have add more properties to the psobject and query the data via the Get-Mailbox cmdlet.

You're already doing something similar here:

```
@{Name="Displayname"; Expression={(Get-Recipient $_.user.ToString()).Displayname.ToString()}}
```

Comment: Thanks, i just dont know...what to add in there....

Comment: You're going to have run (Get-Mailbox $user).SamAccountName to obtain the SamAccountName.
Although my advice would be to put "Get-Mailbox $user" into a variable within the foreach loop so you only have to launch the cmdlet once per iteration. Then all you have to do is call the properties.

Comment: can i get the full syntax friend?

Comment: Nope. I'd rather share these links to get you started on understanding what your script does:

https://ridicurious.com/2018/10/15/4-ways-to-create-powershell-objects/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps

https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2017/06/30/3-ways-to-store-display-results-infrom-a-powershell-variable-at-the-same-time/